# Are attempted edits to deleted comments submitted and shown to moderators?

Tags: support, comments, edits, moderator-tools

It's a known issue that attempting to edit your own comment that has been deleted while you're editing it will result in your edited text [appearing to just disappear into the void without any sort of warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329895/show-a-warning-if-a-comment-is-deleted-while-the-authors-editing-it). However, it might be possible that the attempted edit to the comment might actually be reaching the server and editing the comment in the back-end, and such an edit may be shown to moderators (as they can see deleted comments and their full revision histories).

Are edits that users submit to their own comments that have been deleted while they have been editing it actually saved and shown to moderators, or does the text actually go into complete void?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Signs point to "yes".

It'd generally be difficult to actually find an example of this happening but you linked to a question that linked to another question with a link to a post where this happened... so I was able to get this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of deleted comment and its revisions]

The edit, as you can see, is there and does show up as the actual text of the deleted comment. I was able to confirm that this was the revision the poster was talking about by looking at the timestamps - the edit happened one second after the deletion action.