# What makes a comment substantive enough to deactivate "one-flag deletion" due to "certain keywords"?

Tags: support, comments, flags

Per [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/392799)

> Comments containing certain keywords can be deleted with a single flag.

It [is thought](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9200965#9200965) "thanks" is one of them.

Which for a second was alarming; a single flag can nuke a proper comment requesting clarification / suggesting improvements that ends with "thanks".

But [by testing](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9201268#9201268), it seems substantive comments are exempt. How is substantive defined? I googled using `site:stackexchange.com` but I can't find any info at all on the threshold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Thanks" is indeed one of [Stack Exchange's seven dirty words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/295232). I did some testing a while ago and found out "thanks" comments longer than **40 characters** won't be deleted with a single flag. Other dirty words may have other character limits, or no limit at all.